# Returning the surrounding lines to a string windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting, findstr

I'm using `findstr` to search for a string in a file in the following manner:

```
findstr "test" file.txt
```

This is returning the line where `test` is found, but I would like to return the 3 lines above and below the matching line. I've had a look and it doesn't seem like there are any in-built options to `findstr` to return surrounding lines.

Comment: I have updated my answer to a much better, and more flexible one.

Comment: This is an annoying deficiency in both find and findstr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "hello" file.txt') do (
set /a line=%%a
)
set /a num=0
for /l %%b in (3,-1,1) do (
set /a lines[!num!]=!line!-%%b
set /a num+=1
)
for /l %%c in (1,1,3) do (
set /a lines[!num!]=!line!+%%c
set /a num+=1
)
set /a count=1
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%d in (file.txt) do (
for /l %%e in (%lines[0]%,1,%lines[5]%) do (
if !count!==%%e if not %%e==!line! echo %%d
)
set /a count+=1
)
pause >nul
```

Comment: I don't think this works. Correct me if I'm missing something, but the first FOR loop just sets "line" over and over, so only the last one matters?